# Django throwing an HTTP status code 405 Method not allowed error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django

I'm trying to POST data to REST API but the server responds with an HTTP 405 error. I've tried many options like adding headers to the POST method, changing content type within the POST header but nothing seems to work out.
The exact response from the server is

> {"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}.

**HTML and JS code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    New User Story
    </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('postserviceApp', []);
        app.controller('postserviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.jiraLink = null;
        $scope.reporter = null;
        $scope.assignee = null;
        $scope.Reviewer = null;
        $scope.summary = null;
        $scope.description = null;
        $scope.storyPoints = null;
        $scope.postdata = function (jiralink, reporter, assignee, reviewer, summary, description, storypoints) {
        var data = {
        jiraLink: jiralink,
        reporter: reporter,
        assignee: assignee,
        Reviewer: reviewer,
        summary: summary,
        description: description,
        storyPoints: storypoints
        };



        //Call the services  $http.post('/userStory/story', JSON.stringify(data))
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/userStory/story',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: data
        }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data)
        $scope.msg = "User story created Successfully!";
        }, function (response) {
        $scope.msg = "Couldn't create an User story";
        $scope.statusval = response.status;
        $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
        $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
        };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="postserviceApp" ng-controller="postserviceCtrl">
        <div>
            Jira Link : <input ng-model="jiralink" /><br/><br/>
            Reporter : <input ng-model="reporter" /><br/><br/>
            Assignee : <input ng-model="assignee" /><br/><br/>
            Reviewer : <input ng-model="reviewer" /><br/><br/>
            Summary : <input ng-model="summary" /><br/><br/>
            Description : <input ng-model="description" /><br/><br/>
            Story Points : <input ng-model="storypoints" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Create" ng-click="postdata(jiralink, reporter, assignee, reviewer, summary, description, storypoints)" /> <br/><br/>
        </div>
        <p>Output Message : {{msg}}</p>
        <p>StatusCode: {{statusval}}</p>
        <p>Status: {{statustext}}</p>
        <p>Response Headers: {{headers}}</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Story(models.Model):
    jiraLink = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    reporter = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    assignee = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    Reviewer = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    storyPoints = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm not able to figure out where the problem. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Be sure that the API is expecting a POST and not an GET.

Comment: Yes, got it. Had to inherit from ModelViewSet class instead of ListAPIView class in api.py file and had to add routers to my urls.py file that made django REST framework allow POST requests. Thanks a lot for your help @aUXcoder